# EC2 instance is not in the same VPC as ELB. Invalid Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

Using the AWS CloudFormation service, I am trying to create an Elastic Load Balancer on 2 EC2 instances, but I am getting an error:

> EC2 instance i-0a38204c18b48604c is not in the same VPC as ELB. (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInstance; Request ID: 2af5dc7e-9a7f-11e8-91c9-a3410fab05ba)".

The EC2 instances are getting created properly, but ELB is not created. How can I rectify this issue?

Please find the full code for reference [here](https://pastebin.com/Q14FeBba)

```
 ElasticLoadBalancer:
Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
Properties:
  AvailabilityZones: 
  - 'us-east-2a'
  Instances: [!Ref 'webServer1', !Ref 'webServer2']  
  Listeners:
  - LoadBalancerPort: '80'
    InstancePort: '80'
    Protocol: HTTP
  HealthCheck:
    Target: HTTP:80/
    HealthyThreshold: '3'
    UnhealthyThreshold: '5'
    Interval: '30'
    Timeout: '5'
```

Comment: You need to *actually* paste the code here, not behind a link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified any `Subnets` for your ELB. Therefore, the ELB is being created in the default VPC.

```
VPC -- contains --> Subnets -- contains --> ELB
```

Add the [`Subnets` parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-elb.html#cfn-ec2-elb-subnets) to your ELB:

> **Subnets:** 
>   A list of subnet IDs in your virtual private cloud (VPC) to attach to your load balancer. Do not specify multiple subnets that are in the same Availability Zone. You can specify the `AvailabilityZones` or `Subnets` property, but not both.

Comment: Thanks John. I also tried using Subnets property in the code https://pastebin.com/RqHQ3tUw, but getting an error as below: "InvalidSubnetID.NotFound (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; Error Code: SubnetNotFound; Request ID: 817d6506-9aef-11e8-ad70-d9b8d6317463)". How can i check if the subnet is valid or not for the ELB?

Comment: The `Subnets` parameter is "A list of subnet IDs". However, you provided a string with comma-separated values. That is not the same. You should provide a YAML List, just like you provide values for `AllowedValues` in the `Parameters` section.

Comment: Thanks John, I provided the list to Subnets parameter and it worked :)